# writing values from grid to xml c#

Tags: c#, xml, list, datagrid

I am trying to output the cell values of a data grid to an XML . The cells of the grid are combobox cells with values ALLOCATED, AVAILABLE, OCCUPIED. My xml output needs to be of the form as stated below: (where status is the selected value from the combo box of each cell and Xloc is the row index , YLoc is the column index of that particular cell)

```
<Cell XLoc="1" YLoc="1" Status="AVAILABLE"/>
<Cell XLoc="1" YLoc="2" Status="OCCUPIED"/>
<Cell XLoc="1" YLoc="3" Status="OCCUPIED"/>
```

Currently I am creating a list and saving the combox selected values from the grid ie., AVAILABLE, OCCUPIED....

```
private List<string> Grid_Values()
{
    List<string> CellValues = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < ToolMapGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ToolMapGrid.ColumnCount; j++)
        {
            CellValues.Add(ToolMapGrid.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString());

        }
    }
    ...
}
```

I am writing the above values to XML in this way :

```
List<string> GridValues = Grid_Values();
foreach (string item in GridValues)
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("Cell");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("Status",item);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

I dont understand how do I write Xloc and Yloc values to the XML file. I am returning the combo values as a list but how do I make the same method also return the row and column indexes and how do I write it to the XML file.

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use a DataGrid as a data structure. Write from the table that the grid is DataBound to.

Comment: Its like I need to enter the number of rows and columns and click generate grid button which generates the grid. Then, I need to make my selections in all the cell of the grid. When I am done I click on Generate XML button that writes all my content to XML so datagrid is mandatory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new class called XmlInfo which has three properties, like this:

```
class XmlInfo
{
    string value{get; set;}
    int column {get: set;}
    int row {get; set; }
}
```

After that change your code like this:

```
private List<XmlInfo> Grid_Values()
{
    List<XmlInfo> CellValues = new List<XmlInfo>();

    for (int i = 0; i < ToolMapGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ToolMapGrid.ColumnCount; j++)
        {
            XmlInfo nfo = new XmlInfo { 
                value = ToolMapGrid.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString(), 
                row = i,
                column = j}
            CellValues.Add(nfo);
       }
    }
}
```

Then you can use the code like this:

```
List<XmlInfo> GridValues = Grid_Values(); 
foreach (XmlInfo item in GridValues) 
{ 
     writer.WriteStartElement("Cell"); 
     writer.WriteAttributeString("Status", item.value); 
     writer.WriteAttributeString("XLoc", item.column); 
     writer.WriteAttributeString("YLoc", item.row); 
     writer.WriteEndElement(); 
}
```

You might want to review this for syntax errors, as I typed it directly into the editor and I might have missed something.

Comment: Break it down like this and see what is actually missing:  

`XmlInfo nfo = new XmlInfo();  
nfo.value = ToolMapGrid.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();  
nfo.row = i;  
nfo.column = j;`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented and it worked :)

```
        for (int i = 0; i < ToolMapGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < ToolMapGrid.ColumnCount; j++)
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("Cell");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("XlOC", (i + 1).ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("YLOC", (j + 1).ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("Status", ToolMapGrid.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString());
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }
        }
```